# Light Table editor can't eval defprotocol in cljs source file

Tags: clojure, clojurescript, lighttable

I use Windows 10, first I create project via **Lein new mies**

then I add some content in core.cljs

```
(+ 1 2)

(defprotocol MaybeMutable
  (mutable? [this] "Returns true if the value is mutable."))
```

I select code above and hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd> to eval the code, (+ 1 2) evals correct, but error occurs in defprotocol

> clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo: Can't change/establish root binding of: *unchecked-if* with set

Comment: This seems to be not a question for Stackoverflow. You should create an issue for this on the [project's official repository](https://github.com/LightTable/LightTable) and describe your problem with this IDE there.

Comment: In case anyone want to follow the issue on github: https://github.com/LightTable/LightTable/issues/2282